# Search results null in jquery bootgrid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search, pagination

I am trying to implement JQuery Bootgrid in my project to display the data from MySQL database. The data that I am querying is getting displayed in the pagination table but when I try to search for some data it is showing me that "No result found".I have tested my query on a command line and my Query is OK and it is returning me the desired results.

[image]
[image]
The query is given below:

```
SELECT * FROM radcheck rc LEFT JOIN radusergroup ON rc.username=radusergroup.username LEFT JOIN userinfo ON rc.username=userinfo.username LEFT JOIN radusergroup disabled ON disabled.username=userinfo.username AND disabled.groupname = 'daloRADIUS-Disabled-Users' WHERE username LIKE 'admin';
```

I think there is some problem in the 'WHERE' clause as if I try to use admin in the above query without quotes it shows me an error that ***Unknown column 'admin' in 'WHERE' clause***. The same issue may also be in my PHP code. kindly help..

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
    //fetch.php
    include("connection.php");
    $query = '';
    $data = array();
    $records_per_page = 10;
    $start_from = 0;
    $current_page_number = 0;
    if(isset($_POST["rowCount"]))
    {
        $records_per_page = $_POST["rowCount"];
    }
    else
    {
        $records_per_page = 10;
    }
    if(isset($_POST["current"]))
    {
        $current_page_number = $_POST["current"];
    }
    else
    {
        $current_page_number = 1;
    }
    $start_from = ($current_page_number - 1) * $records_per_page;
    $query .= "SELECT * FROM radcheck rc LEFT JOIN radusergroup ON rc.username=radusergroup.username LEFT JOIN userinfo ON rc.username=userinfo.username LEFT JOIN radusergroup disabled ON disabled.username=userinfo.username AND disabled.groupname = 'daloRADIUS-Disabled-Users'";
    if(!empty($_POST["searchPhrase"]))
    {
        $query .= 'WHERE (rc.id LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR rc.username LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR radusergroup.groupname LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR userinfo.firstname LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
    }
    $order_by = '';
    if(isset($_POST["sort"]) && is_array($_POST["sort"]))
    {
        foreach($_POST["sort"] as $key => $value)
        {
            $order_by .= " $key $value, ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $query .= 'ORDER BY rc.id DESC ';
    }
    if($order_by != '')
    {
        $query .= ' ORDER BY ' . substr($order_by, 0, -2);
    }

    if($records_per_page != -1)
    {
        $query .= " LIMIT " . $start_from . ", " . $records_per_page;
    }
    //echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM radcheck rc LEFT JOIN radusergroup ON rc.username=radusergroup.username LEFT JOIN userinfo ON rc.username=userinfo.username LEFT JOIN radusergroup disabled ON disabled.username=userinfo.username AND disabled.groupname = 'daloRADIUS-Disabled-Users'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

    $output = array(
        'current'  => intval($_POST["current"]),
        'rowCount'  => 10,
        'total'   => intval($total_records),
        'rows'   => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

**users.php**

```
<?php include ("inc/header.php");?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Users</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container box">
        <br />
        <div align="left">
            <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add User</button>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="product_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
                        <th data-column-id="firstname">Customer Name</th>
                        <th data-column-id="username">User Name</th>
                        <th data-column-id="value">Password</th>
                        <th data-column-id="groupname">Groups</th>
                        <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php include("inc/footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php include("inc/script_modal_user.php")?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not closed the bracket in fetch.php near WHERE (rc.id... i closed the bracket and everything worked fine.. thanks

```
if(!empty($_POST["searchPhrase"]))
    {
        $query .= 'WHERE (rc.id LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR rc.username LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR radusergroup.groupname LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" ';
        $query .= 'OR userinfo.firstname LIKE "%'.$_POST["searchPhrase"].'%" )';
    }
```